# Duda con respecto a este código 'new string'

Tags: c#, string

El código es el siguiente:

```
  Console.WriteLine(new String('#', i + 1);
```

Con respecto a esta línea de código que se encuentra dentro de un ciclo 'for', no logro entenderle, ¿alguno sabe cómo funciona la sentencia dentro del cw?, gracias.

Comment: Deberías agregar el código donde está esa línea de código. Es necesario porqué sino como te vamos a explicar para  que sirve esa línea si no sabemos en que contexto la estás usando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si analizamos la documentacion del constructor del string

[String(Char, Int32)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_)

veras que el segundo parametro indica la cantidad de veces que se repetira el caracter

Cuando `i=0` vas a tener un `#`, cuando sea `i=1` tendra un `##` de respuesta, cuando sea `i=2`, el string tendra `###` y asi sigue

Comment: Tssss, muchas gracias de hecho el problema era que dado n números hacer una escalera con esa altura con esas figuras! Excelente respuesta